# olcRootDN: no such attribute openldap

Tags: linux, redhat, openldap, rhel7

I am trying to setup openldap in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.5 (Maipo) and trying to run this command

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f db.ldif
```

which is end up with the following error

> SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started SASL username:
>   gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth SASL SSF: 0
>   modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config"
>
> modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config" ldap_modify: No such
>   attribute (16)
>           additional info: modify/delete: olcRootDN: no such attribute

here is the details of the file content

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=suredev20

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=root,dc=suredev20

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}o8tdQw4jmCVfHyYZ92XtRlc9g+2ukjsJ
```

Even i tried to `:set ff=unix` it also not worked. Whats wrong with my setup?

Edit 1-
I changed like this

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=suredev20

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootDN

olcRootDN: cn=root,dc=suredev20
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}o8tdQw4jmCVfHyYZ92XtRlc9g+2ukjsJ
```

Now i am getting this exception

> modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config" ldap_modify: Other
>   (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
>           additional info:  can only be set when rootdn is under suffix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says `olcRootDN: no such attribute`, so you might just need to *add* it (instead of replace) :

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=root,dc=suredev20
```

It will also probably be the case for `olcRootPW`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you please check edited question with changed suggest by you.

Comment: It seems you missed the last line (in your edit) `olcRootDN: cn=root,dc=suredev20`, otherwise it means `dc=suredev20` is not a valid *suffix*. You can check the base domain components in your directory, this should be set according to (like `dc=suredev20,dc=domain,dc=com`)

Comment: This issue fixed any idea about another issue in another file.modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)

Comment: I did not see it was on the next line.. .ldif syntax takes new lines, tabs and spaces very sensitively.

Comment: So this error is coming cers.ldif file

Comment: I don't know without details but you can open a new question if it's not related and accept this one in that case ( implementation specific error (80) I think it's not a syntax error but another issue)